# В чем ошибка использования strlen?

Tags: c++, строки

```
#include <iostream>

#define MAXLENGTH 128

int main()
{

    char word[MAXLENGTH];

    std::cin.getline(word, MAXLENGTH);

    word[strlen(word) + 1] = 't';
    word[strlen(word) + 2] = 0x30;
    std::cout << word;

    return 0;
}
```

Почему не выводит текст с буквой t на конце?
Правильно ли я пытаюсь задать конец строки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Почему не выводит текст с буквой t на конце?

Конец C-строки обозначется сиволом `\0`. После вызова `getline` буфер `word` содержит символ `\0` в позиции `word[strlen(word)]`. Этот и есть конец вашей строки.

Вы записываете в этот буфер какие-то дополнителные символы *после* символа конца строки, в позиции `word[strlen(word) + 1]` и `word[strlen(word) + 2]`. Эти символы не являются частью строки и никакого влияния не ее содержимое не оказывают.

Что вы и наблюдаете.

Если вы хотели добавить символ `'t'` к вашей исходной строке, то добавлять его надо было *вместо* символа конца строки, а не *после* него. И затем надо не забыть сформировать символ конца строки на новом месте

```
size_t len = std::strlen(word);
word[len] = 't';
word[len + 1] = '\0';
```

> Правильно ли я пытаюсь задать конец строки?

Я не вижу в вашем коде никаких явных попыток "задать конец строки". О чем речь?

Comment: *Я не вижу в вашем коде никаких явных попыток "задать конец строки". О чем речь?* - ну понятно, о том, что человек пытался куда-то записать символ `'0'` - 0x30...

Answer (score 3):

```
strcat(word,"t")
```

будет проще и надежнее... Но если уж вы хотите именно так, как хотите :) - то

```
int l = strlen(word);
word[l] = 't';
word[l+1] = 0;
```

Так как после добавления `t` уже никто не гарантирует, что следующий за ним символ - нулевой...

Ну и, понятно, в обоих случаях остается молиться, чтоб места в `word` хватило на добавление...